# How to get list of all branches created off a GIT branch (get all sub branches of a branch)

Tags: git, git-branch

Is there a way to get the list of all branches created off a branch in GIT.

For e.g. If we have say Rel2 branch created off master, and then we have SP1, SP2 and SP3 created from Rel2 Branch.

Is there any command in GIT to get SP1, SP2 and SP3 as output if i give Rel2 as input ?

Comment: This might help
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch, maybe something like git show-branch --all

Comment: Well I did see that but it doesnt serve the purpose (all switches and modifications, i end up getting all branch commits / branches which I have provided as a key string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just take a commit you want and do

```
git branch --contains commitid
```

in your case you can also do

```
git branch --contains Rel2
```

This will list all branches that have the given commit in their history.

To list **remote branches** do

```
git branch -r --contains commitid
```